# how to submit onchange form without refresh in django

Tags: django, django-forms, form-submit

here is the code where submit onchange

```
                                       <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-7">
                                                <select {{ form|validation_class:"devamsizlik" }} id="devamsizlik" name="devamsizlik" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                                                    <option value="">Gelme durumu</option>
                                                    <option value="True">
                                                        <span  style="font-family: wingdings; font-size: 200%;">&#10004;</span>
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="False">
                                                        <span style="font-family: wingdings; font-size: 200%;">&#10060;</span>
                                                    </option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

ı try some ajax code but none of them working on it , ı could not find anything about while submitting on change page not reload.

Comment: Could you share whole code or your Ajax code

Comment: hello thanks for comment ı deleted them but look from this link:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-form-submission-without-page-reload/